# How do non-trinitarians interpret John 14:26?

Tags: exegesis, trinity, gospel-of-john, non-trinitarian

John 14:26 (NRSV):

> 26 But **the Advocate, the Holy Spirit**, whom **the Father** will send in **my name**, will teach you everything, and remind you of all that I have said to you.

My impression as I read this verse is that three distinct persons are identified, but I could very well be wrong. In the pursuit of having a well-rounded and unbiased view of this passage, I would like to get acquainted with the non-trinitarian perspective on it. Do non-trinitarians also identify three distinct persons being mentioned in John 14:26, and if so, how do they make sense of that?

Comment: Again, there are several forms of non-trinitarians.  Modalists simply see the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit as different "modes" of the one person.  Arians interpret the Holy Spirit as the divine influence of either the Father or the Son, similar to Binitarians.

Comment: The word for 'whom' is mostly translated 'which' in the NT. So they have shown bias in personifying the spirit in this verse.

Comment: @user47952 The 'whom' refers to 'Advocate', clearly a person, since an advocate acts on behalf of another person, and must, therefore, be a person themselves in order to carry out the advocacy.

Comment: @NigelJ https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/49148/john-1416-was-jesus-a-paraclete/49177?r=SearchResults&s=1|51.5936#49177 There's more to it than that.

Comment: Nor does it NEED to be another entity - God does everything in and through spirit. So does Jesus. It's pretty clear that the Father and Jesus dwell in us BY the spirit - not an entity, a means. John 14:23 Logic is less important than plain revelation.

Comment: @NigelJ Correct. The Holy Spirit descended on Jesus at Baptism and He became the Advocate, after His Redemptive mission was over, He commended it to return to the Father. And when Jesus ascended, His first act of mediation is to send it at the Upper Room. This time the Holy Spirit dwells perfectly, completely & mystically in Mary to become the "another Advocate".

Comment: If you want to include a Catholic answer. please do so, as St.Alphonsus Liguori, a Doctor of the Church clearly teaches Mary is the "another Advocate". The Holy Spirit is the Advocate, and Jesus became the Advocate when the Holy Spirit descended on him  to empower His Redemptive mission. And Mary at the Upper Room became the "another Advocate" when the Holy Spirit dwells in Her heart to empower Her Salvific mission. Proverbs9:1 and Sirach24:12

Comment: @jongricafort Can you demonstrate from Scripture that only Mary received the HS in the upper room?

Comment: @MikeBorden I did already. Read Proverbs9:1 and Sirach24:12, and the key passage is Wisdom1:4..The Holy Spirit cannot reside or dwells in a heart that has a stain of original sin. That's why the Apostles receive fire in the head only but not in their heart.Their heart must be purify still.for the Holy Spirit to dwells fully and mystically. St.Paul attained after a long struggles of purification, when he said "it is no longer I who lives, but Jesus". Mary can say that in the Upper Room, but no one from the Apostles can claimed that.

Comment: @jongricafort are you speaking for OP? OP specifically asked fir non trinitarian POV so answering with a catholic answer would be off topic

Comment: @Kris. I asked if he can include a view from Catholicism.

Comment: @jongricafort - if Catholics are non-trinitarians, then go ahead

Comment: We Catholic are Trinitarians, but Nostra Aetate a Vatican II Teachings embraced Non Trinitarian as People of God too. So, if you can accept a Catholic point of view to help you understand John14:26, I will be glad to post my answer. thanks.

Comment: @jongricafort - if you can make clear in your answer that your are presenting a non-trinitarian perspective, I don't see any problems.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember when translating is that the original Greek didn't use upper and lower case or punctuation, and that (like French and Spanish) nouns have gender, so the word for "it" is the same as the words for "she" and "he". (French has "il" and "elle" for "he" and "she", but no word for "it".)

So the first part of this verse could have been translated as "*But the helper, the holy spirit, …*".

Most translations are made by people that either believe in, or accept for translation purposes, the doctrine of the Trinity.
So it is natural for them to treat the words as referring to a person and capitalize them.

If the verse instead said:

> But the helper, the holy spirit, which the Father will send in my name, will teach you everything, and remind you of all that I have said to you.

there is no reason (other than doctrinal eisegesis) to treat the sentence any differently than:

> But the Bible, the Holy Book, which the Father will send in my name, will teach you everything, and remind you of all that I have said to you.

Most Christians would accept that sentence as true, without ever thinking that "Bible" and "Holy Book" are meant to refer to a person.
It's only when one is already aware of the Trinity doctrine that the other interpretation arises.

To those that have no reason to believe that "holy spirit" refers to a specific person, God's holy spirit is literally that: the spiritual power through which God works.
It has no more individual personality than does air or water.

Christians receive some of this spirit at baptism, and combined with their own human spirit it provides them with intimate contact with God.

[The Power of the Holy Spirit | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/the-power-of-the-holy-spirit) is an example of this doctrine.

Comment: The example "But the Bible, the Holy Book" does not in anyway, can be compare to the Holy Spirit..Bible is a non living thing...one cannot blaspheme a bible, the bible cannot be grieve, it has no feelings.

Comment: @jongricafort, I suspect you are a Trinitarian, and you are letting that belief influence your reasoning.  *Is* the holy spirit alive?

Comment: More than alive. The Holy Spirit is the giver of life itself. Genesis2:7

Comment: @jongricafort, Genesis 2:7 says "*And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living being.*".  Even if the holy spirit is the giver of life, it doesn't follow that it is itself alive.
And unless one already believes in the Trinity, there is nothing there that even hints or implies that there is a "Holy Spirit" that is a member of the godhead, much less that this spirit is itself alive. ¶ On this site, only the textual evidence is supposed to be used, not additional knowledge based on doctrine.

Comment: the answer could be improved by explaining what "helper" and "holy spirit" refer to if they are impersonal.

Comment: @eques, The Greek word "*paraklētos*", translated here as "*helper*", is elsewhere translated as "*advocate*", "*comforter*", and "*counselor*".
It is simply the part of God's spirit that lives within and guides those that have accepted it.
There is nothing about the word to indicate that it refers a self-aware being.
In fact, 1John 2:1 uses the same Greek word "paraklētos" to refer to Jesus himself. If one weren't already aware of the Trinity concept, they certainly wouldn't be able to develop that doctrine based on this verse.

Comment: @RayButterworth my point was that it belongs in the answer. Nothing in your answer actually says that those terms are not personal nor does it say what a spirit is otherwise. Given that, doctrinal debates are off-topic, that's about the extent of critique I could really offer --  but there are naturally Trinitarian contras to your assertions

Comment: @RayButterworth additionally, your correct definitions of the Greek terms point out though a "personal" or at least "animate" quality to the words, so it seems like the answer would be benefited by explaining how those words are understood if describing an animate agency; i.e. who is "helping"

Comment: The spirit intercedes for us (Romans) , can be grieved (Isaiah, Proverbs, and Ephesians), and can be lied to (Acts). He is the God you'll never know.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0, Treating something *as if it were* a person isn't unusual.
People yell at their TVs, punch their steering wheels, refer to their GPS voice as "her", etc.
¶ "intercession" means "to go to a person … for the purpose of conversation, consultation or supplication" (Theayer's "*entygchanō*").
God's spirit within one does exactly that; it allows communication with God.
¶ When what it has to report to God is bad, "aggrieved" isn't an inappropriate term.
¶ To "lie to" the spirit is to tell the spirit to lie to God.

Comment: So lying on my taxes is lying to the government. But my taxes don't get "aggrieved!" I know you won't be convinced (because that is HIS job - convincing of sin, righteousness, and judgement), so I will leave you in peace.

Comment: This answer in substance amounts not to actually stating what a particular Unitarian perspective is but claiming a sort of confirmation bias in interpretation by Trinitarians using a claim around capitalization. It would be greatly improved by explaining how Unitarians understand helper, spirit, send, etc AND how the capitalization "confirmation" is explained given with the Trinity doctrines were first elaborated, modern capitalization also did not yet exist

Comment: @eques, The question is specifically about how those denominations that don't believe that God's holy spirit is a separate "person" interpret John 14:26. The answer is: no, non-Trinitarians don't identify three distinct persons in that verse.

Comment: No, the question is HOW do non-trinitarians understand the verse. It's obvious they don't understand it as different persons otherwise they'd be Trinitarians (or Tritheists perhaps). So in other words, saying, no it's not persons is insufficient. It's incumbent to say then what helper, spirit, etc refer to.

Comment: @eques, sorry, I must be somewhat asleep at the wheel today.  I've added more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several forms of non-trinitarianism, I can only comment on LDS doctrine.

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints teaches a Godhead comprised of three distinct persons (or beings since persons is an overloaded term in trinitiarian doctrine) working together as one. So for LDS, this scripture is simply interpreted as that - the Holy Spirit is sent by the Father in Jesus name. Nothing mysterious going on, just emphasizing the unanimity/oneness of the Godhead. Sent by the Father, but acts on behalf of Jesus (just like Jesus acts on behalf of the Father).